# Append null string in socket connection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sockets

I am doing a socket connection and writing a data through a socket,I need to and null string at end of my data like,

myMethod=ABC||10D=12345||phNumber=zzz||lang=english and at last after english I need to append null string,please help me with this.

Comment: If you require to press Enter Key to accept or ping then you need to do '\r'(carriage return) or '\n' (new line feed). If you only need to append a Null then '\0'. As What is your exact requirement...Here are few thing that I faced while making my first socket program :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya hi thanks,but when I added \0 and then I print string I was not able to see \0 ,is it just because I am appending null ??

Comment: yes this in invisible character.

Comment: Vishwa, did it worked? if yes then do accept the answer.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya hi it's appending null character but it's not writing on socket.any do you have any suggestion for socket prgrm class for ios?

Comment: google yaar, you will find many codes for socket connections, even from apple documentations. iOS has a lot more codes available in net, I work for mac applications there a lot of extra codes/efforts need to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply append  NULL word which is : "\0"

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *nullEndedString = @"myMethod=ABC||10D=12345||phNumber=zzz||lang=english\0";
```

`\0` means `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You can add null at the **beginning** of the character by using

```
char bytes[] = "\0name\0surname";
NSString * mystring = [NSString mystring];
[mystring initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
NSData * data = [mystring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can use above code according to your functionality.